# How can I display a pop up message if something isn't found?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Question is I have a query that looks at my emp_id text box once something is typed in it searches for the information tied to that emp_id which in my other table that it searches for its called ID.. If the emp_id matches the id in my visual model it will populate their first name and last name for them. I would like to know how I can get it to display an error if no emp_id matches an id in my visual model....

This is my visual model

```
 class Visual < ActiveRecord::Base

 establish_connection :vtest

 self.table_name = 'employee'


 Visual.inheritance_column = 'inheritance_type'

 belongs_to :user

 def emp_matches(x)
   (x.id.to_i == self.id.to_i ? true : false)
 end
end
```

This is my user controller that has the my populate form method

```
 class UserController < ApplicationController


   def populate_form

     @visual = Visual.find_by_id(params[:emp_id])

     if @emp_matches == 'False'

       respond_to do |format|

         format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity, flash[:error] => "Error No ID found." }
     end

   else

     @visual = Visual.find_by_id(params[:emp_id])

     @emp_first_name = @visual.first_name

     @emp_last_name = @visual.last_name


      render :json => {

         :emp_first_name => @emp_first_name,
         :emp_last_name => @emp_last_name
      }
  end
end
```

And here is my App.js

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

   $('#emp_id').change(function() {
         var url = "/user/populate_form?emp_id="+$(this).val();
         $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
           if(!(data.emp_first_name === undefined))
           $('#emp_first_name').val(data.emp_first_name);
           if(!(data.last_name === undefined))
           $('#emp_last_name').val(data.emp_last_name);
         });
       }
     );
   });
```

My tables

Visual model

```
      Table is called Employee 
        ID
        first_name
        last_name
```

User model

```
      Table is called User 


        emp_id
        emp_first_name
        emp_last_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a notice in your view.

Have a look at the following: [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash.html)

This might help.